# Web app Java desplegada en Heroku no reconoce Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, heroku

Estoy practicando Java JSP + Tomcat server 10.0.23 y tengo un problema con el proyecto desplegado en Heroku.

La página comienza en un index.jsp que tiene un formulario el cual lanza un post request hacia un Servlet.
El Servlet recibe, almacena la info en una base de datos y hace una redirección hacia otro archivo jsp para informar del resultado.

Debería funcionar de esta forma, y de hecho localmente lo hace, pero en el proyecto desplegado tira un error al no encontrar el servlet.
Lo que me resulta raro es que en la url de la página aparece el nombre del Servlet, cosa que no debería llegar a pasar por la redirección programada.

Quizás no configure correctamente algún archivo del proyecto para que funcione de igual manera que en local.
Si alguien tiene el conocimiento y predisposición disponible, le puedo dar mayor detalle del problema.

**Src folder:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_5_0.xsd"
         version="5.0">
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ServletDatabase</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.gabit.dev.makeawish.controllers.ServletDatabase</servlet-class></servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ServletDatabase</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ServletDatabase</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**Error:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El servlet lleva la anotación @WebServlet(name = "ServletDatabase", value = "/ServletDatabase") y el formulario del index.jsp apunta a ServletDatabase a secas.

Lo deplegue con estos comandos:

```
mvn package
heroku deploy:war .\target\Make-A-Wish-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war -a java-makeawish
```

Agradezco de antemano cualquier ayuda.

Comment: La versión por defecto de [Tomcat en heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/configuring-war-deployment-with-the-heroku-toolbelt#setting-the-tomcat-version) es la 9.0.20.0 y me temo que esa versión no tiene soporte para jakarta. Deberás usar los paquetes de javax.* si quieres desplegar tu servicio en este servidor. Para jakarta.* necesitas mínimo TomCat 10.

Comment: Estuve buscando como podría cambiar la versión de Tomcat en heroku, ya que tengo entendido que la versión 9 podría tener problemas con los Servlets. La única forma que encontré hasta ahora, requiere hacer cambios en el pom.xml y crear una clase Main que lanza el servidor. Lo intenté pero me tira un error que no encuentra la clase Main cuando quiero probarlo.

Answer (score 1):

Como heroku usa la versión 9 de Tomcat, reemplace las referencias a paquetes Jakarta por Javax tanto en la definición del Servlet como en el archivo pom.xml.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).